# Calling webservice with complex parameters from c# client

Tags: webservices-client

**Hello, Here is a class ...**

public class Authentification
    {

```
    private string userField;
    private string passwordField;
    public string user
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.userField = value;
        }
    }

    public string password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.passwordField = value;
        }
    }

}
```

**here the web service :**

```
[WebMethod]
public Vehicle[] getVehiculeList(Authentification authentification)
{
....
}
```

**Here the client and the call of webservice :** 
(the same class Authentification like in the webservice has been defined)

```
Authentification azz = new Authentification() ;
azz.user = "toto";
azz.password = "tata";
string aa = ws.getVehiculeList(azz);
```

gives an error : 
Error   27  The best overloaded method match for 'WSCL.localhost.Service1.getVehiculeList(WSCL.localhost.Authentification)' has some invalid arguments

and

Error   28  Argument '1': cannot convert from 'WSCL.Authentification' to 'WSCL.localhost.Authentification'

Any help ?

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

What might have happened is that you have referenced the assembly containing the data entities (e.g. Authentication) on your client, and now you have both the proxied entity (`WSCL.localhost.Authentification`) and the original server entity (`WSCL.Authentification`). If you change your client's use of Authentication to use the proxied class (`WSCL.localhost.Authentification`) it should work.

If you switch to WCF, you will be able to move the data entities like Authentication into a separate assembly, and then Share this same type between your Service and your Client. AFAIK this isn't possible 'out of the box' in [ASMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154408/creating-web-service-and-client-with-shared-types).